# spring icon for components is missing in eclipse editor ruler

Tags: eclipse, spring-tools-4

Watching the [STS 4 Presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v14bhGRo_zk)  i noticed that these little green spring icons for the beans are actually useful to have in your editor (starting watching from 22:50 to know why). These are the Icons I'm talking about:

[[image: Icons I'm talking about]]

However, i dont have them in my eclipse installation (a WTP + STS4 plugins and others) nor do i see them in a current **vanilla install and workspace** of spring-tool-suite-4-4.5.0.RELEASE-e4.14.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar.

The only things I see is the eclipse code mining, but no icons, eg:
[image]

So, has this changed in STS 4 in the meantime (video is from Dec 2017) or what settings do i need to change to make them visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has changed quite a bit since that presentation, so I would recommend to take a look at the user manual for that feature:

https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Live-Application-Information

This is up-to-date with the latest Spring Tools 4 release that you mentioned and explains the way to enable and see that live information for Spring apps. Side note: the icons on the side are gone, but the sections in the code are shown with a green background.